# Pandas check if value in one multiindex column is in any column, same row of different multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 7, 0, 1, 8, 3, 0],
                   [7, 3, 4, 0, 4, 9, 7, 0]], 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["first", "second"], 
                                                      ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]))
print(df)

  first          second         
      A  B  C  D      A  B  C  D
0     0  1  7  0      1  8  3  0
1     7  3  4  0      4  9  7  0
```

I want to check, whether the values in first are present in any of the columns of second. Only the same row should be compared.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
      A      B      C     D
0  True   True  False  True
1  True  False   True  True
```

What is the best way of doing this? I have already played around with df["first"].isin(df["second"] but it only compares A with A, B with B, ... Also tried it in combination with .any() but I can't seem to make it work.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Numpy broadcasting

```
np.any(df['first'].T.values[:, :, None] == df['second'].values, axis=-1).T
```

---

```
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: Thanks to you and all the others that answered! I accepted this answer as it seemed to perform the best on my dataset. This answer took 0.0022 seconds, @Quang Hoang's 0.0125 seconds and ashkangh's 1.9600 seconds.

Comment: This is a GREAT solution, very well formed, you ROCK Shubham cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution:

```
df['first'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(df.loc[x.name, ('second')]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A         B       C      D
0   True    True    False   True
1   True    False   True    True
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option with `isin` and a for loop on `A,B,C,D`:

```
seconds = df['second']
np.any([df['first'].isin(seconds[c]) for c in seconds], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of numpy functions, along with `zip`:

```
In [79]: step1 = zip(np.split(df['first'].to_numpy(),2), 
                     np.split(df['second'].to_numpy(), 2))

In [80]: step2 = [np.isin(arr1, arr2) for arr1, arr2 in step1]

In [81]: np.vstack(step2)
Out[81]: 
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True]])
```

You can pass it to the DataFrame constructor to return a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(step2), columns = df['first'].columns)
Out[82]: 
      A      B      C     D
0  True   True  False  True
1  True  False   True  True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `.isin()` and `.T`

```
df['first'].T.isin(df['second'].T.to_dict('list')).T
```